# Setting property 'antiJARLocking' to 'true' did not find a matching property

Tags: java, maven, servlets

My context.xml file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/candy"/>
```

How can i get rid of this warning? My project is running on Netbeans and Tomcat 8.0.9:
**Setting property 'antiJARLocking' to 'true' did not find a matching property**

Comment: It was removed in Tomcat 8; supported before that. Have a look at `antiResourceLocking`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Remove the attribute from the context.xml file. Tomcat does not support it.

Answer (score 19):

antiJARLocking is an attribute in **Tomcat 7**, which has been removed in Tomcat 8.

So, for **Tomcat 8**, just use antiResourceLocking.

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/context.html